# PHP: breaking a function to functions with a single task?

Tags: php, laravel

I have a function that performs about 5 tasks at the same time that is strictly against the principles of OOP. can anyone help me to break it dawn? specially calling a function in other function is a kind of tricky for me.

```
public function status(){
        $client = new Client();
        $notification=Notification::where('active',1)->get();
        $status = Status::where('name', 'health')->first();
        $default_frequency = 1;

        foreach ($notification as $note) {
            $status_health = $note->status('health');

            $check_frequency = isset($note->check_frequency) ? intval($note->check_frequency) : $default_frequency;

            $date = \Carbon\Carbon::parse($status_health['timestamp']);
            $elapsed_time = $date->diffInMinutes();

            if($elapsed_time < $check_frequency){
                continue;
            }

            $response = $client->get($note->website_url, ['http_errors' => false]);   
            $resCode = $response->getStatusCode();

            $note->statuses()->attach($status,['values'=> $resCode === 200 ? 'up' : 'down']);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Well you itemise the 5 tasks you want to make into seperate methods and someone might well help you

Comment: yes. because this class so important and i will call the functions from different class repeatedly. that is why i want to break it dawn now.

Comment: Yes I know but **Give us a list of the 5 tasks in this code that you believe you want to break out into 5 new methods** I dont see 5 seperate tasks so I am obviously stupid and need your assistance

Comment: this class is responsible for sending 1,http request 2, it checks the time stamp of the checks with the current time in order to send the http request. 3,  it attachs ( this is actually part of the http_request) 4,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you need to refine the code too much. If I understood correctly, you're trying to update the status of your notifications within some specified intervals.

This could be break into two tasks:

1. Getting all notifications and loop through each one of them
2. Update the status of each notification based on some criteria

Here is my attempt to refine and simplify your code a little:

```php
Class YourClass {

    const DEFAULT_FREQUENCY = 1;

    private $client;

    public function __construct(Client $clinet)
    {
        $this->client = $clinet;
    }

    public function status()
    {
        $notifications = Notification::where('active', 1)->get();
        $status = Status::where('name', 'health')->first();

        foreach ($notification as $notification) {
            $this->updateStatus($notification, $status);
        }
    }

    private function updateStatus(Notification $notification, Status $status)
    {
        $status_health = $notification->status('health');

        $frequency = $this->getFrequency($notification);

        $elapsed_time = \Carbon\Carbon::parse($status_health['timestamp'])->diffInMinutes();

        if ($elapsed_time >= $frequency) {
            $response = $this->client->get($notification->website_url, ['http_errors' => false]);   
            $notification->statuses()->attach($status, [
                'values'=> $response->getStatusCode() === 200 ? 'up' : 'down'
            ]);
        }
    }

    private function getFrequency(Notification $notification)
    {
        return isset($notification->check_frequency) 
            ? intval($notification->check_frequency) 
            : self::DEFAULT_FREQUENCY;
    }
}
```

Comment: tnx for the response. i will read and try it if it works for me.... appreciate it

Comment: works perfectly as expected! what i really want to return this class is that if the response code is not 200 then it should then i will call it in a different class to send slack or e mail notification? if we can give me hints or help ?

Comment: You can inject the other class in your class constructor (similar to what we did with `Client` class). Then once you checked your $response code and it was not 200, you can call the other class's method for further processing (i.e. sending notifications)

Comment: instead of injecting, i just thought of doing simple return http code and then use the result in other class and then decide either to send notification or not? if we may try to edit your code.

Comment: I cannot comment on what's the best way to design your code since I don't know the details of what you're doing. The only thing that you need to keep in mind is that each class/function has to have a single responsibility. So if the current class is responsible for updating the notification status, leave the code as it is and delegate other stuff to other classes/services to handle.

Comment: 1. You are passing the slack class as a dependency through the constructor (well done) but you are not using it. Instead you are using the Slack class as static (`Slack::send(...blablabla`)
2. But GuzzleController class shouldn't be depending on Slack. But it should depend on another class. Let's call it `Reporter` and its job would be to report to certain channels when needed